# Como selecionar com Expressão Regular uma tag xml/html completa mesmo que haja tags iguais internamente?

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte tratamento em uma string em javascript utilizando ER (Expressão Regular):

Com essa entrada: `um <b>negrito<b>negrito interno</b>externo</b> aqui <b>negrito</b> <i>italico</i>.`, gostaria de obter a `tag` `<b>` completa, com todo o seu conteúdo até seu par de fechamento `</b>`, sendo esse o resultado esperado: `<b>negrito<b>negrito interno</b>externo</b>` e `<b>negrito</b>`.

Mas não estou conseguindo considerar que uma `tag` pode conter outra mesma internamente, sendo que consegui chegar no máximo até esse resultado (que não considera a possibilidade de uma `tag` igual internamente, como pode ser visto no primeiro resultado onde é `<b>negrito<b>negrito interno</b>` ao invés de `<b>negrito<b>negrito interno</b>externo</b>`:

```js
var entrada = 'um <b data-remove>negrito<b>negrito interno</b>externo</b> aqui <b>negrito</b> <i>italico</i>.';
var regex = /<(b)>.*?<\/\1>/g;

// limpa DOM para imprimir
document.body.innerHTML = "";

entrada.replace(regex, function(match) {
  console.log(match);
  // para imprimir do DOM
  document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(match));
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  return match;
});
```

```css
body {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

Meus conhecimentos de ER são limitados, e chegaram praticamente no limite nesta situação. Então aguardo alguma preciosa dica de algum *expert* em ER, ou um "Esquece isso não é possível com ER =(".

**Edit 2** Solução esperada:

A forma que procuro e não sei como fazer seria algo que fosse contando/acumulando as ocorrências de tags de abertura e ignorando os fechamentos até que seja o fechamento par referente a abertura (equivalente a primeira tag de abertura).

> Se houver duvidas comente!

**Edit 1:** Meu caso real para melhor entendimento do problema:

> Este exemplo real tem o intuito apenas de demonstrar o contexto onde estou utilizando a função em questão, e o por que de não poder fazer isso via jQuery ou qualquer outro parser no DOM do navegador. Pois necessito deixar o DOM correto, para que o CSS seja aplicado de forma correta e somente após a conversão para style inline que posso remover o que era somente para o Browser renderizar corretamente e ai então obter o resultado de meu template esperado.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btnGenerateHtmlMail').click(function(ev) {
    var $report = $('#report');
    convertCssToInlineStyle($report);
    var reportHtml = $report.html();
    reportHtml = reportHtml
      /* remove class attribute */
      .replace(/class=('|").*?\1/g, "")
      /* remove id attribute */
      .replace(/id=('|").*?\1/g, "")
      /* remove comments html */
      .replace(/<!--.*?-->/g, "")
      /* remove tab, enter and whitespace */
      .replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')
// ----->>>   // esse é o meu caso de problema, nesse exemplo não da problema pois nnão há tags iguais dentro do tr, mas sei que isso seria um bug que quero resolver para tornar a ferramenta generica
      .replace(/<(tr) data-remove="true".*?>.*?<\/\1>/g, function replacer(match) {
        console.log(match);
        return match.match(/{{.*?}}/g);
      });
    $('#result').text(reportHtml);
  });
});


/* Metódos irrelevantes para o problema */

function getCssDeclared($elem) {
  var sheets = document.styleSheets,
    o = {};
  for (var i in sheets) {
    var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
    for (var r in rules) {
      if ($elem.is(rules[r].selectorText)) {
        o = $.extend(o, css2json(rules[r].style), css2json($elem.attr('style')));
      }
    }
  }
  return o;
}

function css2json(css) {
  var s = {};
  if (!css)
    return s;
  if (css instanceof CSSStyleDeclaration) {
    for (var i in css) {
      if ((css[i]).toLowerCase) {
        s[(css[i]).toLowerCase()] = (css[css[i]]);
      }
    }
  } else if (typeof css == "string ") {
    css = css.split("; ");
    for (var i in css) {
      var l = css[i].split(": ");
      s[l[0].toLowerCase()] = (l[1]);
    }
  }
  return s;
}

function convertCssToInlineStyle($root) {
  $root.each(function() {
    var $item = $(this);

    var style = getCssDeclared($item);
    $item.css(style);

    // recursive call chields
    convertCssToInlineStyle($item.children());
  });
}
```

```css
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
}

table td, table th {
 padding: 8px;
 padding-top: 3px;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
 line-height: 1.428571429;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table > tfoot {
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="report">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr data-remove="true">
        <th>{{theadContent}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-remove="true">
        <th>{{tbodyContent}}</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr data-remove="true">
        <th>{{tfootContent}}</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="tools">
  <button id="btnGenerateHtmlMail">
    Gerar HTML E-mail
  </button>
  <div contenteditable="true" id="result" style="width: 99%;resize: none;border: 1px solid #ccc;padding: 0.5%;"></div>
</div>
```

> Obs: Nesse exemplo (real) não da problema pois não há tags iguais dentro do tr, mas sei que isso seria um bug que quero resolver para tornar a ferramenta genérica.

Comment: Esse código é server-side (Node.js, IO.js), ou você vai rodar isso no browser mesmo?

Comment: @ctgPi, Browser mesmo, client-side.

Comment: Condense sua questão. Tem muita informação desnecessária. Mostre apenas a sua questão bem especificada e o que você já tentou. Apenas explicite que precisa que seja com Regex. Não precisa justificar a sua necessidade.

Comment: @Guill, estava sem meu exemplo real e acabou vindo respostas muito longe da solução, então tentei adicionar o problema quase que completo para entenderem o contexto do problema. Mas vou ver se removo algumas coisas que podem ser irrelevantes para o probelma em meu código real.

Comment: @Guill, sim funciona para qualquer numero de ocorrência interna (Já editei e removi) mas não é o que é esperado olhe [esse exemplo de sua solução para o meu caso real](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/ufuLf197/), estou achando que isso não é possível =(.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24753/discussion-between-guill-and-fernando).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como dito pelo [@ctgPi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68900/como-selecionar-com-express%C3%A3o-regular-uma-tag-xml-html-completa-mesmo-que-haja-t/69017#comment140682_68925):

> HTML não é uma linguagem regular e portanto não pode ser processada por uma expressão regular.

Por tanto é necessário se escrever funções para realizar o processamento de HTML.

Aqui uma amostra de código em que se pode trabalhar (utiliza expressões regulares).

```js
// String com seu HTML
var string = '<table><thead><tr data-remove="true"><th></th><th><th>{{theadContent}}</th></th><th></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr data-remove="true"><th>{{tbodyContent}}</th></tr></tbody><tfoot><tr data-remove="true"><th>{{tfootContent}}</th></tr></tfoot></table>';

// Converte a String em Objeto JQuery
var $element = $(string);

//Itera sobre as raízes realizando as substituições necessárias
$('*[data-remove=true]', $element).each(function(index) {
  $(this).replaceWith($(this).html().replace(/.*?(\{\{[^\}]*\}\}).*/, '$1'));
});

// Converte o objeto JQuery em String
var string_processada = $element.get(0).outerHTML;

// Imprime na tela
$('body').text(string_processada);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Ela corta ramificações de DOM cuja raíz tenha o atributo `data-remove` com valor `true`; deixando apenas o trecho envolvido em "{{" e "}}".

Pode conter *bugs* que eu não vi.

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que você está tentando processar uma linguagem que não é regular (HTML) com expressões regulares. A solução é você escrever uma função recursiva que faz a limpeza, algo tipo:

```
var attributeWhiteList = ['style'];  // atributos que você quer deixar
var elementWhiteList = ['#text', 'TABLE', 'THEAD', 'TBODY', 'TFOOT', 'TR', 'TH', 'TD', 'P', 'B', 'DIV'];  // elementos que você quer deixar

function cleanHTMLForEMail(node) {
    if (node.nodeName === '#text') {
        // aqui você editar node.textContent pra tirar espaço em branco
        return node;
    }

    // listar atributos
    var attributeNames = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < node.attributes.length; i++) {
        attributeNames.push(node.attributes[i].name);
    }

    // tirar todos os atributos fora da whitelist
    for (var i = 0; i < attributeNames.length; i++) {
        if (attributeWhiteList.indexOf(attributeNames[i]) === -1) {
            node.removeAttribute(attributeNames[i]);
        }
    }

    // listar filhos
    var children = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
        children.push(node.childNodes[i]);
    }

    // tirar todos os filhos fora da whitelist
    // e limpar os que estão dentro
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (elementWhiteList.indexOf(children[i].nodeName) === -1) {
            node.removeChild(children[i]);
        } else if (children[i].nodeName === 'TR' && children[i].dataset.remove === 'true') {
            node.removeChild(children[i]);
        } else {
            node.replaceChild(cleanHTMLForEMail(children[i]), children[i]);
        }
    }

    return node;
}
```

**Editado:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufuLf197/1/), ajeitando pequenos erros da implementação, e funcionando no exemplo que você queria resolver.

Comment: Não sei se eu não entendi sua solução, mas o que quero é que o resultado [desta estrutura deste exemplo (que funciona)](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/fre1ckub/1/), e que [está outra estrutura com `<tr>` dentro de `<tr>`](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/v8u0uccq/) possa ter o mesmo resultado da anterior. Não sei é possível entender o problema? E não entendi no que a sua solução pode ajudar?

Comment: Se eu entendi você quer “descascar” as linhas da tabela (tirar o `<tr>` e deixar o miolo)? Ds tags que contém `data-remove="true"`, você só quer o texto contido no interior delas?

Comment: Tá, vi no outro comentário o que o `data-remove="true"` quer dizer. Entre os `{{` e `}}`, só tem texto puro, ou pode ter tags? Se pode ter tags, algo te impede de trocar `{{` e `}}` por, e.g. `<div data-preserve="true">` e `</div>`?

Comment: O seu primeiro comentário está perfeito, é exatamente isso que quero.

Comment: Tipo [isso aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/ufuLf197/3/), então? Eu só troquei a linha que trata os `<tr>` no código acima.

Comment: a respeito de seu segundo comentário, entre o `{{` e o `}}` só pode ter texto, no máximo algo similar a isso: `{{cliente.nome}}` (com o ponto). E a respeito da marcação, ela será utilizada por outro framework em Java que irá substituir, por exemplo: `{{cliente.nome}}` por "Fernando". Entendeu?

Comment: Saquei. Olha o segundo JSFiddle então; eu acho que ele resolve a sua vida.

Comment: Uhm, aparentemente funcionou, por enquanto +1, vou analisar certinho aqui e se for o caso marco como resposta. Olha ele funcionando [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/fre1ckub/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Não tenho certeza se entendi o seu problema. Geralmente apenas utilizamos ER para a validação de dados.

Expressões regulares: introdução

http://turing.com.br/material/regex/introducao.html

Quando precisamos alterar adicionar ou remover algum elemento do HTML costumo utilizar os seletores jquery.

http://simplesideias.com.br/usando-jquery-na-pratica

Comment: Tipo esse não é meu caso, estou a fazer um tratamento da string do DOM, uso o $('body').html() para tratar o regex. A aplicação trata-se de uma API para converter CSS para _style_ _inline_ (para HTML Mail), e esse é um tratamento final já com o html com _style_ _inline_ já no formato de string. Mas mesmo assim agradeço a atenção e disposição em ajudar.

Comment: Desculpe ainda não entendi a finalidade que você precisa dessa solução. Seria para verificar se todas as tags html foram fechadas e para validar de a estrutura do html está correta ?

Comment: Nem um, nem outro. O exemplo real na pergunta [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/fre1ckub/), pode-se ver o funcionamento correto da aplicação, que para este determinado caso está funcionando, pois não há tags `<tr>` dentro de outra tags `<tr>`. Onde o que faço é remover toda a estrutura marcada com `data-remove="true"` mantendo a estrutura interna marcada entre `{{` e `}}`. Faço essa marcação com `data-remove="true"` para que o html ao ser renderizado antes de converter o css para style inline, não se modifique como demonstrado [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/7qrcupj7/).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode (e na minha opinião deve) usar o próprio parser do navegador:

```
buffer = document.createElement('div');
buffer.innerHTML = 'um <b>negrito<b>negrito interno</b>externo</b> aqui <b>negrito</b> <i>italico</i>.';
console.log(buffer.querySelectorAll('b'));
```

Se você só quer os `b` em primeiro nível, você pode criar dois `div`, um dentro do outro, e procurar apenas `div > b`.

(pelo que eu testei, isso parece ser imune a XSS contanto que você descarte o nó resultante e não o insira diretamente no documento)

Comment: Vou postar uma outra resposta pra pergunta atualizada.

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente esta Regex funciona para o seu problema. Em algumas amostras ela deve falhar. Mas para o seu problema serve.

`\<(minhaTag)(?: .*?)?\>(?:[^\<]|\<(.*?)\>[^\<]*\<\/\2\>)*\<\/\1\>`

[Regex Testada Aqui](https://regex101.com/r/hT1rU8/5)

Substitua `minhaTag` pelo nome da *tag* desejada. Esta *regex* vai referenciar o elemento mais superficial da *tag* especificada e seu conteúdo. O elemento pode conter atributos.

### Dicas:

- Tenha cuidado com os operadores `*?` e `*` estude as suas diferenças.
- Lembre-se de incluir `\n` (nova linha) à classe `.` através do modificador *single line* (`s`), no caso deste modificador ser suportado.
- Utilize o modificador *global* (`g`) para o caso de querer todas as *tags* superficiais especificadas na amostra (*vide* o link acima).

Comment: HTML não é uma linguagem regular e portanto não pode ser processada por uma expressão regular.

Comment: @ctgPi, na pergunta em nenhum momento trata `var entrada = 'um <b data-remove>negrito<b>negrito interno</b>externo</b> aqui <b>negrito</b> <i>italico</i>.';` como um conteúdo HTML de fato, e sim como uma string com um determinado padrão, então na minha opinião esses seus comentários nas respostas seriam inválidos. Pois essa é a resposta que mais se aproximou da solução até então.

Comment: O meu comentário é uma afirmação matemática — [um teorema](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lema_do_bombeamento_para_linguagens_regulares), para ser mais preciso. A `var entrada` é, sim, uma string, que **representa** um fragmento de HTML; [ela não é o cachimbo, ela é a representação do cachimbo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Trai%C3%A7%C3%A3o_das_Imagens). É totalmente válido usar strings pra representar HTML quando ele está sendo passado de um lado pro outro (no caso, via email); é _errado_ manipular a string quando o que você quer é manipular o HTML subjacente.

Comment: @Guill, com sua ultima edição voltamos ao inicio novamente, [olhe o que acontece de adiciono um `<tr>` dentro do outro](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/ufuLf197/2/). Isso está parecendo mais complicado do que imaginava. =(

Comment: Aqui funcionou como esperado. Use o link do bate-papo no comentário na pergunta. Para não poluirmos os comentários. Mais ainda.